# I want to get exact Nth ordinal week from start date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

e.g.

`moment('2010-01-01').add(52 * 4,'week').format('YYYY-MM-DD') // "2013-12-27"`

I want to get "2014-01-01", i.e. 4 years later.  I realize there aren't *eaxctly* 52 weeks in a year and moment accounts for leap years, etc.

Any elegant way to achieve this with momentjs, short of writing a loop from the start date and rounding to nearest week.

A bi-monthly solution is also acceptable, ie, '2010-01-01' + (6 * 4y) = '2014-01-01'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to do with moment.js because you can simply so with *pure JS* like

```
//your date is 2010-01-01
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 4); //returns 2014-01-01
```

---

Updates(with string parsed to date object):

```
var ds = "2010-01-01";
var dsArray = ds.split("-");
var date = new Date(dsArray[0], (+dsArray[1])-1, dsArray[2]);
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 4);
console.log(date);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/q4wXm/)

Comment: 4 years was just an example.  Please re-read the question.  It's the 52 (or *Nth ordinal week*) I'm interested in.